# One subprcess starts whereas the other doesn't

Tags: python, discord.py

I basically want to run multiple python scripts. There were many ways of doing this but basically preferred the following one:

```
import subprocess
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    subprocess.call(['python','fileA.py'])
    subprocess.call(['python','fileB.py'])
```

However, fileA runs, but fileB doesn't. Only after closing the first, the second starts. I tried with os.system, but same happens there too. Please help. I need both files to **run** simultaneously.

Comment: `run` is not an asynchronous call, so the files will run one after the other- can I ask why you are not using the files like a library, importing the contents and running the pertinent code using a multithreading library?

Comment: `subprocess.call()` *waits for the command to complete*. Does that command complete?

Comment: @Philp Adler, I do not wish to import them as library because these python scripts do not end. These are infinite running until the program is killed.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct - this is still run sequentially due to the Python script in which `subprocess` is embedded.

What I think you're looking for is the [Python 'threading' module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). This will allow you to set up your threads (`subprocess` of `fileA.py` and `fileB.py`), then execute them at the same time.

Note that this is **not** multiprocessing (which is a lot more complex), and because of this, your main script will not continue until all threads are complete.

Comment: I am not able to understand the documentation. I am kinda new to python and I am just 15. Could you just tell me  how to just start fileA and fileB simultaneously with that tread thingy?

Comment: @RaebelChristo Good for you for starting so young. I haven't done threading in a while, so I had to look over it myself; I think the 'threading' library is more complex than you need (depending on what `fileA` and `fileB` do, of course). I would actually go with the lower-level (and simpler) 'thread' module (Python2: `import thread`, Python3: `import _thread`). When you run the linked example, you'll see the lines aren't always printed in the same order, showing that it's running concurrently in separate threads. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7g3xi7umzh2z73d/thread_example.py?dl=0